# [Spring-Boot]Controller required a been named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my spring application.
Below is the copy of the pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties> 

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent> 

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>       
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version> 5.2.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

Below is the copy of the application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-204-18-53.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d695rcqcr9r06e?user=poevxwkkkdcuho&password=d519b6781db3cdf4c615df7c24deaa2ef741f47458cb98c66e5d1b6f68c3e3c8&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
spring.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx    
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource



spring.jpa.properties.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
#hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect

logging.level.org.org.springframework.retry=DEBUG
management.security.enabled=false
```

Error trace i got is as below.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-10-28 14:27:56.545  INFO 16678 --- [           main] com.loanguruhub.RestController           : Starting RestController on TheKing with PID 16678 (/media/dhiral/Media/java/gs-loanguru-hub/target/classes started by dhiral in /media/dhiral/Media/java/gs-loanguru-hub)
2018-10-28 14:27:56.554  INFO 16678 --- [           main] com.loanguruhub.RestController           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-28 14:27:56.810  INFO 16678 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@28c4711c: startup date [Sun Oct 28 14:27:56 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-28 14:27:58.871  INFO 16678 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'clientDetailsService' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/configuration/ClientDetailsServiceConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=authorizationServerConfig; factoryMethodName=clientDetailsService; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/loanguruhub/security/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]]
2018-10-28 14:28:00.785  INFO 16678 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-10-28 14:28:02.022  INFO 16678 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-10-28 14:28:02.070  INFO 16678 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.070  INFO 16678 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-10-28 14:28:02.099  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.286  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-10-28 14:28:02.287  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5490 ms
2018-10-28 14:28:02.854  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.855  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.855  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.855  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.856  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.856  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'corsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-28 14:28:02.856  INFO 16678 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-10-28 14:28:03.017  WARN 16678 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'companyController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'companyResouces'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyResources': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#75504cef' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#75504cef': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2018-10-28 14:28:03.024  INFO 16678 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-10-28 14:28:03.072  INFO 16678 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-28 14:28:03.219 ERROR 16678 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field companyResouces in com.loanguruhub.controller.CompanyController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I am stuck in between. I have tried few things. Since hibernate-JPA starter providing entityManager is remvoed hibernate-core and hibernate-entity-manager from pom.xml as well. But the same error i got. In addition to that i have create custom datasoruce as below.

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and tried to do the same thing. but got same error again. any help is appreciable.

**======Update=======**
CompanyController code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
        path = "/company",
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class CompanyController {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyResources companyResouces;
}
```

Error trace relate to the JDBC-URL

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Please post your CompanyController.java

Comment: @DeadSpock :- updated

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things need to fix then should work..

1. As you are using spring data jpa so hibernate is default implementation so no need to explicitly define hibernate dependencies as this might create conflict so remove this from pom:

   ```
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version> 5.2.1.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. As you are also passing data source user name and password so remove passing param from url: so remove username and password from it `spring.datasource.url` and have only username and password from `spring.datasource.username` & `spring.datasource.password`.
3. from spring boot 2.x `hikari` is default connection pool and Spring data jpa will auto configure your data source based on application .properties so also remove configuration also: so remove below class:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class DatabaseConfiguration
   ```

Comment: Error thrown after following above steps :- dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1063) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]

Comment: its not spring.datasource.jdbc-url, its spring.datasource.url, I have also corrected in my answer

Comment: I have make changes accordingly. but the same error is there. Error trace from start is updating on question.

Comment: remove this too : spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource